# SQL Code to compare and do cumulative based on condition

Tags: mysql, sql, hana

As shown in the image:

[image]

[image]

Here I need to perform cumulative based on a condition:

I have

```
   Column 1: Sales Date
   Column 2: Warranty End Date
   Column 3: Qty of Sales
   Column 4: Cumulative Sales Qty
```

**Now for Column 5: Under warranty** which gives a wrong value here 
  when the warranty dates complete 365days(expires) I need to subtract the sales happened for that expiry date in the under warranty count column similar the count starts reducing for the following days when the warranty expires.

For eg in the figure:
JAN 1,2014 have 246 as cumulative sales when it reaches JAN 1 2015, I need to subtract that **'246'** from **'96502'** which is the cumulative sales till **JAN 1 2015**.So should be **96256**

How can we achieve the logic in SQL for 'Under warranty count' column

My Query:

```
SELECT a."sales_year", 
       a."sales_billing_date", 
       a."warranty_end_date", 
       a."sum_val", 
       a."order_qty", 
       CASE 
         WHEN Sum(Days_between (a."warranty_end_date", a."sales_billing_date")) 
              < 365 
       THEN a."sum_val" 
         ELSE ( ( a."sum_val" ) - ( b."sum_val" ) ) 
       END AS "Under_Warranty" 
FROM   "_SYS_BIC"."pal/cv_pal_tbf_sales" a, 
       "_SYS_BIC"."pal/cv_pal_tbf_sales" b 
GROUP  BY a."sales_year", 
          a."sales_billing_date", 
          a."warranty_end_date", 
          a."order_qty", 
          b."sum_val", 
          a."sum_val";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `SALES_BILLING_DATE` AND `WARRANTY_END_DATE` are 1 year apart throughout the table, you can do a self join by matching above two columns from each instance of the table and doing the subtraction on the `UNDER_WARRANTY` amount.

```
SELECT A.SALES_YEAR, A.SALES_BILLING_DATE, A.WARRANTY_END_DATE, A.SUM_VAL, A.ORDER_QTY,
(A.UNDER_WARRANTY - B.UNDER_WARRANTY) AS UNDER_WARRANTY_NEW
FROM
YOUR_TABLE A
INNER JOIN
YOUR_TABLE B
ON A.SALES_BILLING_DATE = B.WARRANTY_END_DATE;
```

To retain 2014 entries in the output, try the below query. Changed to left join with the same `ON` condition and if there is no match then the `UNDER_WARRANTY` amount remains unchanged.

```
SELECT A.SALES_YEAR, A.SALES_BILLING_DATE, A.WARRANTY_END_DATE, A.SUM_VAL, A.ORDER_QTY, 
CASE WHEN B.WARRANTY_END_DATE IS NOT NULL THEN (A.UNDER_WARRANTY - B.UNDER_WARRANTY) ELSE A.UNDER_WARRANTY END AS UNDER_WARRANTY_NEW
FROM
YOUR_TABLE A
LEFT JOIN
YOUR_TABLE B
ON A.SALES_BILLING_DATE = B.WARRANTY_END_DATE;
```

Comment: How can include 2014 data also becase when inner join happened 2014  disappears,but i should update  2014 data with same a."UNDER_WARRANTY" value.  For eg: WHEN (a."Sales_Year" = 2014 )
THEN
a."UNDER_WARRANTY"

Comment: thank a lot. can u please help with one more similar kind of issue                                              https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48577382/cumulative-sum-grouped-by-multiple-parameters